# How to control the power of attiny13a via pin change interrupt?

Tags: attiny, avrdude, attiny13

I'm trying controll the power of attity13a and turn off/turn on the led.
I'm going to goals:

- After to click on the button0
  led will blicking 5 second nad then the attiny13a going to sleep.
- After to click on the button1 then wake attiny13a up and then led will shane.

The button0 to sleep and blink the led.
the button1 to wake up and turn on the led.
Could you explain what is wrong in this sketch, please?
thank you for your answers.

[image]

**code:**

```c
    #define F_CPU   1200000UL
    #define LED     PB2 // PB2
    #define BUTTON1 PB1 // PCINT1
    #define BUTTON0 PB0 // PCINT0

    #define HIGH         1
    #define LOW          0
    #define INPUT        0
    #define OUTPUT       1
    #define INPUT_PULLUP 2
    #define FALSE        0
    #define TRUE         1
    #define _BV(bit)    (1 << (bit))

    #include <avr/io.h>
    #include <avr/interrupt.h>
    #include <avr/sleep.h>
    #include <util/delay.h>

    void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode)
    {
        if(mode == OUTPUT) // Pin as output
            DDRB |= _BV(pin);
        else // Pin as input or input pullup
        {
            DDRB &= ~_BV(pin); // Set pin as input
            if(mode == INPUT_PULLUP)
                PORTB |= _BV(pin); // Enable pullup resistors
        }
    }

    void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val)
    {
      if(val)
        PORTB |= _BV(pin);  // Set pin high
      else
        PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // Set pin low
    }

    uint8_t digitalRead(uint8_t pin)
    {
      return !!(PINB & _BV(pin));
    }

    // go to sleep
    ISR(PCINT0_vect)
    {
       if(digitalRead(BUTTON0)){
            int i=0;
            while(i<10){
                blink();i=i+1;
            }
            set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
            sleep_enable();
            sleep_cpu();
        }
    }

    //wake up
    ISR(PCINT1_vect){
       if(digitalRead(BUTTON1)){
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
       }
    }

    void blink(){
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
        _delay_ms(500);
        digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
        _delay_ms(500);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        pinMode(BUTTON0, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT_PULLUP);

        pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

        // Sets the Pin change interrupt mask PB0, PB1
        PCMSK |= _BV(PCINT0)|_BV(PCINT1);   

        //Enables Interrupts globally after setup
        //sei();
        SREG |= _BV(SREG_I); 

        while(TRUE){}
    }
```

Comment: Does the program work? If not, what is its behavior?

Comment: The led is on and nothing happens when click on the buttons

Comment: How is the LED wired?

Comment: Note that `blink()` lacks a delay in the `HIGH` state, and the tiny13 has no `PCINT1_vect`.

Comment: The short leg of led connected to GND.
The long leg of led connected to the resistor (1kOm) and to PB2

Comment: Updated the function of blink.

Comment: Could you explain, please, how to correctly go to power saving mode and wake attiny up from power saving mode?

Comment: You need to enable PCIE in GIMSK for PCINT interrupts to be recognised. Also all interrupts go through PCINT0_vect and you have to differentiate the pins within that.

Comment: Beside the problems stated above, your code also doesn't account for switch-bounce.

Comment: is the program actually being loaded into the attiny13a? ... are you able to run a simple program that blinks the LED?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
#define F_CPU   1200000UL

#define LED     PB2 // PB2
#define BUTTON1 PB1 // INT0
#define BUTTON0 PB0 // PCINT0

#define HIGH         1
#define LOW          0
#define INPUT        0
#define OUTPUT       1
#define INPUT_PULLUP 2
#define FALSE        0
#define TRUE         1
#define _BV(bit)    (1 << (bit))

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void pinMode(uint8_t pin, uint8_t mode){
    if(mode == OUTPUT) // Pin as output
        DDRB |= _BV(pin);
    else // Pin as input or input pullup
    {
        DDRB &= ~_BV(pin); // Set pin as input
        if(mode == INPUT_PULLUP)
            PORTB |= _BV(pin); // Enable pullup resistors
    }
}

void digitalWrite(uint8_t pin, uint8_t val){
  if(val)
    PORTB |= _BV(pin);  // Set pin high
  else
    PORTB &= ~_BV(pin); // Set pin low
}

uint8_t digitalRead(uint8_t pin){
  return !!(PINB & _BV(pin));
}

//wake up
ISR(INT0_vect){
   sleep_disable();
   //cli(); // Turn off global interrupts
   digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
}

void blink(){
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    _delay_ms(1000);
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    _delay_ms(1000);
}

// go to sleep
ISR(PCINT0_vect)
{
   //cli(); // Turn off global interrupts
   if(!digitalRead(BUTTON0)){
        cli(); // Turn off global interrupts

        blink();

        digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

        sei(); // Turn on global interrupts
        set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
        sleep_enable();
        sleep_cpu();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    //enabled external interrupt
    MCUCR=0;
    //MCUCR=0b00000000;
    GIMSK|=_BV(INT0); // enabled external interrupt INT0 - PB1

    // Sets the Pin change interrupt mask
    GIMSK|=_BV(PCIE);
    PCMSK|=_BV(PCINT0);//PB0

    pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);       
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);

    pinMode(BUTTON1, INPUT_PULLUP);//INT0 - PB1
    pinMode(BUTTON0, INPUT_PULLUP);//PCINT0 - PB0

    //Enables Interrupts globally after setup
    //SREG |= _BV(SREG_I); 
    sei(); // Turn on global interrupts
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sleep_enable();
    sleep_cpu();

    while(TRUE){}

    return 0;
}
```